# How can I group several mercurial repositories in one?

Tags: mercurial

I'm working on a project that use Mercurial as his source control manager.

The directory structure is the following:

repo/mylib1/.hg
repo/mylib2/.hg
...
repo/myApp/.hg

I want everything under an unique repo (ie: repo/.hg) and, ideally, I want to keep the file history of each repo.

Can I do that with Mercurial? How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can [combine repositories](http://hgtip.com/tips/advanced/2009-11-17-combining-repositories/) or split a repository into [separate ones](http://hgtip.com/tips/advanced/2009-11-16-using-convert-to-decompose-your-repository/)

Comment: I finally used the technique exposed in the post you are reffering to. But instead of using "hg addremove", I use "hg mv" to keep my history.

Thanks!

Comment: Cool I'm glad it worked out for you. HG is deceptively powerful for moving history around, I never cease to be amazed at what it can do.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use Mercurial's relatively new support for [subrepos](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/subrepos).